# How to access cookies (Capybara/Selenium Chrome Webdriver)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, testing, cookies, capybara

I've been able to find loads and loads of examples that claim that `page.driver.cookies` should work but there is no such method on `Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Driver` (which is what `page.driver` is).

I've been trying to dig around with pry to find anything that responds to `cookies`, `cookie_jar`, `set_cookie` or `clear_cookies` but there seems to be nothing. Not on `page`, `page.driver` or `page.driver.browser`.

I also don't quite get the sentiment that reading cookies isn't a thing in testing (the RackTest driver exposes `#cookie_jar` but `Rack::Test::Methods` only forwards `set_cookie` and `clear_cookies`). Why shouldn't I test a middleware that sets a cookie under certain conditions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you shouldn't be testing cookies directly, is because feature/system tests are the wrong place for that. Those types of tests are designed to test things from a users perspective, and users don't actually see cookies they just see the behaviors cookies enable. Therefore, in Capybara tests, you should just be testing the behaviors enabled by cookies not that the actual cookies are set. The setting/clearing of cookies is really something that should be tested for in controller or request tests.

If you still insist on accessing cookies directly then they are accessible using JS via `evaluate_script` or via selenium driver specific methods `page.driver.browser.manage.all_cookies`, etc. - although any time you're calling `page.driver.xxx` you're probably doing something you shouldn't be.

Comment: I settled for a request spec. I figured it's not only correct but faster. With Chrome I also ran into another problem that request specs solve: signed/encrypted cookies.

Answer (score -2):

Just from reading [this documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/support_packages/working_with_cookies/), have you tried something like this:

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome

begin
  driver.get 'https://www.example.com'

  # Adds the cookie into current browser context
  driver.manage.add_cookie(name: "key", value: "value")
ensure
  driver.quit
end
```

Comment: The question is about Ruby but you’re showing the JS selenium API.

Comment: Sorry, that link *does* have a code example that seems to work though,